# how to substitute continous same words with one word in vim?

Tags: regex, vi

I want to  substitute  continous same words with  one word in vim ,that is to say to keep just one word , substitute `kitty kitty` with `kitty` ,substitute `world world` with `world`,and so on.

Why my regular expression in vim is wrong?

```
:%s/\<\(\w+\)\>\s\1/\1/g
```

Comment: Hey, it's not nice to alter the question after you got an answer to the original text.

Comment: To answer your sub-question (you could have made it a comment to my answer) - you can use `\(\1\s*\)\+` to repeat the partial match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `+` needs to be escaped in vim regular expressions.

```
:%s/\<\(\w\+\)\>\s\1/\1/g
```

---

You can reduce the amount of escaping by enabling [magic mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/magic) with the `\v` switch.

```
:%s/\v<(\w+)>\s\1/\1/g
```

Magic alters the syntax of vim regular expressions quite a bit. Be sure to read the documentation. Especially in longer, meta-character-ladden regexes it can improve length and readability, though.

Comment: why `:%s/\<\(\w\+\)\>\(\s\+\1\)\+/\1/gc` can not substitute `kitty kitty   kitty  kitty` with `kitty`? `\(\1\s*\)\+` can not represent to repeat the partial match.

Comment: `\v<(\w+)>\s+(\1\s*)+` works for me (which is just what I recommended, only with `\v`)